# How to validate a UI in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

My UI is simple. In a Silverlight 5.0 application, I'm using MVVM and I let the user adds many textboxes as he wants to add in a `ObservableCollection<Model>` and a `Button`.

`Model` just have one property and its datatype is an `integer`.

The data template for this model is just a simply textbox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" />
```

So the idea is, when all the textboxes does not have any error, the command is enabled, but if any model has an error, the command should be disabled.

How can I implement this validation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply throw an exception in appropriate property`s setter:

```
public int Number
{
    get {//...}
    set {
           if(value >= 10)
             throw new Exception("Number should be less than 10");
           _number = number;
        }

}
```

And your binding should be:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Mode="TwoWay" ValidateOnExceptions="True"}" />
```

FrameworkElement has [BindingValidationErrorEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bindingvalidationerror%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which can be used for implement enable/disable command logic. Remember to set `NotifyOnValidationError` to `True` for your binding.

p.s.Also, i suggest you read about [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Ohh I see, so which the last interface, I can check in my viewModel if my models has an error right?

Comment: if you implement INotifyDataError or setter (as in example below) in your `Model` class you can validate it.